# Replacing special chars in a string in order to use JSON.parse()

Tags: javascript, json, string, replace

I have a string

```
var test = '[{"ident": "success"}, {"records": {"0": {"organisation": "Microsoft"}, "1": {"organizacja": "\"a"}}}]';
```

How can i replace `\"` with `\\"` so i can parse it with JSON.parse? Anyone know this?

Comment: `\"` would be read as `"`

Comment: Please edit  your question as it is not clear what you want to replace `\"` with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
test.replace(/\\"/g, '\\\\"');
```

Comment: @AnhTuan this may help you :)

Comment: I still can't parse it with JSON.parse

Comment: @AnhTuan just alert like this alert(test.replace(/\\"/g, '\\\\"')); and see your \" replace to \\"

Comment: I have a code like this.

var data = xmlhttp.responseText.replace(/\\"/g, '\\\\"');
console.log(data);
var data = JSON.parse(data);

Still the console informs me that the parsing was not ok.

Answer (score 1):

Your question must sounds like - how I can get valid json string from object using [java, php, python], and then use it with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this,

```
> var test = '[{"ident": "success"}, {"records": {"0": {"organisation": "Microsoft"}, "1": {"organizacja": "\\"a"}}}]';
> console.log(test)
[{"ident": "success"}, {"records": {"0": {"organisation": "Microsoft"}, "1": {"organizacja": "\"a"}}}]
> console.log(test.replace(/\\"/g, '\\\\"'))
[{"ident": "success"}, {"records": {"0": {"organisation": "Microsoft"}, "1": {"organizacja": "\\"a"}}}]
```